# JAVA Dynamically build up an ANDED IF statement

Tags: java, json

If i have 5 optional parameters that be passed by GET API call how can i filter the array of JSON and get desired results.

Basically if all 5 parameters are passed i can check in an 'ANDED' IF statement as follows

```
if (obj.get(address).toString().contains(searchRequest.getAddress())
                        && obj.get(car).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchRequest.getCar())
                        && properties.get(name).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchRequest.getName())
                        && properties.get(job).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchRequest.getJob())
                        && properties.get(salary).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchRequest.getSalary())
```

searchRequest contains 5 fields which can optional be passed to GET REST call which will work fine, but if only two fields are passed which is allowed how can i build up correct ANDED IF statement so for example if only searchRequest.getAddress() and searchRequest.getName() are passed i would want

```
 if (obj.get(address).toString().contains(searchRequest.getAddress())
                        && obj.get(name).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchRequest.getName())
```

and ignore the other 3 fields

Comment: Can you share your current code? Please ask your question as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please format your question properly, as it stands it is unreadable and likely to get closed. Do not use quote blocks (prefixed with >) for your own question text, and use code blocks for code (indent by 4 spaces).

Comment: For dynamic parameters, you can use MultiValueMap....

Comment: Are you implementing a REST endpoint for others to call or are you trying to call a REST endpoint from some 3rd party? If you are building your own REST endpoint: are you using any framework like Spring Boot for example?

Comment: I provide this GET endpoint which allows for 5 optional search pararmeters to be passed  
if all 5 fields passed then this IF is valid if json field == passed parameter 1 && json field == passed parameter 2 && json field == passed parameter 3 && json field == passed parameter 4 && json field == passed parameter 5

but if field 2 and field 5 are passed only then i only want

if json field == passed parameter 2 && json field == passed parameter 5

is there a way to dynamically build up the valid IF statement based on which parameters are passed in java

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparison method:

```
public static <T> boolean equalsIgnoreCase(T a, T b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a == null || b == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return a.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(b.toString());
    }
}
```